# Isolated spectral value

Tags: spectral-theory

My question is about self-adjoint operators (general unbounded) in a separable Hilbert space.
Must an isolated spectral value of such operator belong to the point spectrum?
Does the answer for the above question change for non separable Hilbert spaces?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes. And it follows from the spectral theorem. For example, you can consider it in the multiplication operator form. For instance if $T$ is a bounded self-adjoint operator on a Hilbert space $\mathcal H$ then it is unitarily equivalent to multiplication by the identity. More precisely, there exists a unitary operator 
$U:{\mathcal H}\rightarrow \oplus_{n=1}^N L_2({\mathbb R},d\mu_n)$ for some measures $\mu_n$, such that

$$
(M\phi)_n(x)=x\phi_n(x),\qquad M=UTU^{-1}.
$$

Now, if $\lambda$ is an isolated value of the spectrum, then proving that it is an eigenvalue is equivalent to proving that $\mu_k(\{\lambda\})>0$ for some $k$ (with eigenvector given by $\phi_n(\lambda)=1$ and zero everywhere else $\phi_m$ identically zero for $m\neq k$).

But if every $\mu_n(\lambda)=0$, then $M-\lambda I$ will have an inverse given by multiplication by $1/(x-\lambda)$, which is well defined since